# Dictionary with range as key

Tags: python, dictionary, range

In Python, how can I map from a range of values to one concrete value?
Basically, I want a dictionary, which I can fill with ranges and index with numbers:

```
rd = rangedict()
rd[(0, 10)] = 5
print rd[4] # prints 5
print rd[6] # prints 5
rd[(5, 15)] = 20
print rd[4] # prints 5
print rd[6] # prints 20
```

Comment: A quick google using 'interval' rather than 'range' leads to https://code.google.com/p/intervalmap/ and http://joshuakugler.com/archives/30-BetweenDict,-a-Python-dict-for-value-ranges.html

Comment: (1) Does not allow overwriting.
(2) Uses linear search instead of efficient hashing, no updating of values.
Both do not solve the requirements I stated in the question.

Comment: The question, in its current form, does not appear off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @user4815162342: borderline, perhaps. Reopened, we'll see how this goes.

Comment: Does "prints 4" mean "prints 5"?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for reopening. Agreed that the question could be better - for example, it fails the "what have you tried" test. But it's definitely not "off-topic" on SO. Also, I see no problem with the original reference to a Java library. It does not imply that the question itself is asking for tool recommendation, it is merely clarifying the intent. For all the OP knows, Python's batteries-included standard library might well support equivalent functionality out of the box.

Comment: Sounds like you could use something that looks like a [Segment Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), but a standard implementation will not work I guess.

Comment: @knub: Don't refer to hashing as "efficient" in this case, as the most likely optimal data structure for your purposes is either an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).

Comment: Why not `{i: 5 for i in range(0, 10)}` to do it?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: you would need to resolve ambiguous queries: point 5 could belong to more than 1 intervals.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: Also, this only works for integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I could find a solution using the `intervaltree` package.

```
from intervaltree import IntervalTree

tree = IntervalTree()
tree.addi(0, 10, 5)
print tree[4]
print tree[6]

# need to chop before, as the library stores both intervals otherwise
tree.chop(5, 15)
tree.addi(5, 15, 20)
print tree[4]
print tree[6]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an interval tree

pip install intervaltree

```
from intervaltree import Interval, IntervalTree
rd = IntervalTree()

rd[0:10] = 5
print rd[4]
print rd[5]
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree