# numeric range in dict constant

Tags: python

Looking for a way to write the dictionary constant.

For example,

EXAMPLE = {0~10: 'low', 11-20: 'medium', 21:30: 'high}

is there a way to code 0~10 where I can do EXAMPLE[5] and it will output 'low'?

Comment: In `O(1)` or is `O(N)` ok, too?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, are you saying I have to write it like EXAMPLE = {0:'low', 1:'low'... etc} ?

Comment: That, or use some external library which gives you that functionality.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This will only work for integers, though

Comment: Why not just use if statements?

    if n <= 10:
        print('low')
    elif n <= 20:
        print('medium')
    elif n <= 30:
        print('high')
    else:
        pass # handle it however you want

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ None of the answers there actually address the generic issue of getting `O(N)` range lookup. The one "library" does iterate the underlying dict :)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yep, I don't think there's a way around the O(N) without replicating data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  yes there is.

Comment: @wim If there is (well, there probably is), I'd love to see an answer on one of the marked dupes!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Of the top of my head I think I could cook up a tree based `O(logN)` approach...

Comment: @schwobaseggl Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34718595/4909087?

Comment: more like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852283/key-lookup-from-a-data-structure-based-on-range

Comment: @wim Hmm.. Do you know of any`O(1)` algorithm for arbitrary ranges when the ranges aren't as regular that there is a simple function (like floor) that can calculate the range from the value.

Comment: Nope, I only know O(log n).  I'm not saying O(1) doesn't exist, just that I don't know how to do it..

Comment: You can have some clever hash function to do so. For example, in this one, you can have `vals=['low','medium','high']`, and for some arbitrary number `n`, you can do `vals[n%10]`. You can likely do something similar for whatever case you're thinking of as long as you're guaranteed a continuous mapping from inputs to outputs

Comment: @wim That's how I should start wording my sentences from now on. Thanks for the link.